# Store level Inventory for individual product Magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento2, multistore, inventory, quantity, cataloginventory

Is there any way that have enable Store level Inventory.

Its not about user config Inventory at

> Catalog > Inventory

Its about

> Admin >> Catalog >> Product >> Open product which you want to add >> Inventory >> Minimum Qty

I need them on product level with store level, There is no way that it can be changed to Store level.

Ex => *Two stored one is retail and other is wholesale, How can I set quantity increment only with wholesale So that user select bulk of 5  Qty and in Retail it should be one Qty increment.*

- Retail store = 1 Increment
- Wholesale store = 5 Increment

This increment differ with product.

[image]

Comment: is it possible, Is there any one to get it out.

Comment: did you found solution & do you need solution now ?

Comment: I need solution I dint fine it.

Comment: It is possible to assign stocks to websites in Magento 2.3+. If you need to assign stocks to store views then you can use extensions like Store View MSI Sales Channel

Answer (score 4):

Untill magento 2.2.6 you can not assign / allocate inventory on store level or website level basis. inventory is managed **globaly** so you will have single inventory across all stores / websites.

However in magento 2.3 , MSI (MultiSource Inventory ) is introduced but as per [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.0OpenSource.html) that is available on website level not on store level.

to manage inventory on store level you would need 3rd party ware housing extension , like you can check one of following extension :

1 - [Amasty multi warehouse inventory](https://amasty.com/multi-warehouse-inventory-for-magento-2.html)

2 - [AITOC multi location inventory](https://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_multi_location_inventory.html)

3 - [wyomind advanced inventory](https://www.wyomind.com/magento2/advanced-inventory-magento.html)

These are few which you can use for your site to multi stock / warehousing.

Comment: I would recommend against using the Wyomind multi-warehouse extension. I just recently finished a site launch for a client using that extension, and as a developer, it was a headache to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this in 2.2.0 without custom extensions. On the database level a product has only global inventory settings stored in cataloginventory_stock_item table.

I'd suggest to look for multi-stock extensions.

Comment: Thank You, If I am going to write my own it will be a lot of coding right, Let me try.  Is there any free extension to do it.

Comment: I think it will be, you'll have extend the database, the logic and the indexers. I don't know if there are any free extensions, it is quite hard to implement this, so I doubt. However, MSI (Multi-Source Inventory) will be featured in 2.3, so take a look at that.

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade to 2.3 or 2.3.1 you can then set store stock on a website level using the new MSI stock system without the need for third party modules such as Wyomind.

I have just replaced the Wyomind advanced inventory module with the new magento MSI

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was not full. Please check if the MSI Product Sources Configuration extension works for you. You can set configuration options on a source level.

[image]